# Preserving LVM Partitions while installing ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, lvm

I decided to make the switch from OpenSuse to ubuntu. I use lvm with opensuse and I wanna have my partitions in ubuntu. The only option I see in installation is to erase everything and use lvm which I can't use and "do something else" which says "use lvm for encryption" which is not useful. How can I keep my current virtual partitions under ubuntu?

Thanks in advance,